# Online service to email a file from particular URL

Tags: email, services

Anybody know free online service which allows email a file which is located on a particular URL to a specified email without downloading a file to local computer?

As an example: I have some URL for mobi file and want email it to Amazon Kindle email so a file will be automatically sent to a Kindle device, but I cannot connect Kindle to a PC to upload a file via USB, also I cannot download a file to my PC to email it myself.

I'm not sure whether SuperUser is the right place for this question, if no - sorry for offtopic and please suggest the right one Q&A resource.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any cloud hosting service such as Dropbox. You don't even need to install the software, just upload the file the file in the web interface and share it with the chain link when you hover over the uploaded file.

Other options would be:

- Google Drive
- Skydrive

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I cannot upload a file since it is located on a particular URL. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Use the *[Save to Google Drive Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en)* to save a document available as a link to your Google Drive without having to download it first to your computer.

Description from the extension's home page -

> The Save to Google Drive Chrome extension helps you save web content
>   to your Google Drive.
>   * Adds a browser action to save the current page.
>   * Adds a right-click context menu to save hyperlinks and media.
>
> This extension allow you to save web content directly to Google Drive
>   through a browser action or context menu. You can save links to
>   documents, images, and HTML5 audio and video all by right clicking and
>   selecting 'Save to Google Drive'. You can save the currently viewed
>   page using the 'Save to Google Drive' browser action. The format of
>   saved HTML pages can be controlled with the extension's options page
>   (Choice of Entire image (default), Visible image, Raw HTML, MHTML, or
>   Google Doc).

Comment: And then can I email it somewhere?

Comment: @sll Within Google Drive, you can select the file, click on the More dropdown button, select the Share option and then choose "Email as Attachment" or "Email Collaborators"